# how to get the average price in group by clause

Tags: sql-server, group-by, average

I run this to find out if there are more of the same records of `OEMNumber`:

```
USE [ISTABLocalDB]
SELECT OEMNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM [file].[ItemPart]
GROUP BY
    OEMNumber
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image]

how do i then find the average price of column price1, price2 and price3 and group it together with the oemnumber if there is more than 1 of the same record

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
      [OEMNumber]
      ,[Price1]
      ,[Price2]
      ,[Price3]
  FROM [ISTABLocalDB].[file].[ItemPart]
```

[image]

Comment: Just addon `AVG(Price1),AVG(Price2),AVG(Price3)`in your 1st query.

Comment: that did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

USE [ISTABLocalDB]

```
SELECT 
    OEMNumber, AVG(price1) AS Price1, AVG(price2) AS Price2, AVG(price3) AS Price3
FROM 
    [file].[ItemPart]
GROUP BY
    OEMNumber
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the following?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [OEMNumber],SUM(ISNULL(c.price,0))/COUNT(NULLIF(c.price,0)) AS av
FROM [ISTABLocalDB].[file].[ItemPart]
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(Price1),(Price2),(Price3)) c(price)
GROUP BY OEMNumber
```

This is a sample:

```
;WITH tb(Id,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6)AS(
   SELECT 1,6,1,2,3,4,5 UNION
   SELECT 2,0,0,2,0,4,5 UNION
   SELECT 3,0,1,2,0,4,5 UNION
   SELECT 4,0,1,0,3,0,5 UNION
   SELECT 5,0,1,0,3,0,5 UNION
   SELECT 6,0,1,0,0,4,5

)
SELECT id,SUM(ISNULL(c.n,0)) AS total,COUNT(NULLIF(c.n,0)) AS cnt
       ,SUM(ISNULL(c.n,0))*1.0/COUNT(NULLIF(c.n,0)) AS av FROM tb
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(n1),(n2),(n3),(n4),(n5),(n6)) c(n)
GROUP BY id
```

```
id          total       cnt         av
----------- ----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
1           21          6           3.500000000000
2           11          3           3.666666666666
3           12          4           3.000000000000
4           9           3           3.000000000000
5           9           3           3.000000000000
6           10          3           3.333333333333
```